# Does value of the integral stay unchanged if we change the value of function at countable number of points?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and then let $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by, $$ g(x)= \begin{cases} f(x)  &,\, x \in[a,b]\setminus E \\ K &, \, x \in [a,b]\cap E\end{cases}$$ where $K$ is any real number and $E$ is a countable (finite or countably infinite) subset of $[a,b]$.

Now if $f \in R[a,b]$ then is it the case that $g \in R[a,b]$ **with** $ \int\limits_{[a,b]}g=\int\limits_{[a,b]} f$?

The notation $f \in R[a,b]$ seems to have caused confusion. Apologies for that, by that notation, I meant $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$

---

My question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1405102/552998) result. According to it, $f \in R[a,b]$ then is it the case that $g \in R[a,b]$

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm assuming as long as measure of $E$ is $0$? Well that's nice to know but I'm happy with this being true for countable as of now. If this is a well known result, could you point me to a proof of it?

Comment: If you think about it purely in terms of measure theory, the deletion of a null set will not change the integral since the integral of any (measurable) function over a null set is zero.

Comment: No, the result at that link does not show what you say it shows! You need to assume the closure $\overline E$ has measure zero...

Comment: @FShrike Wow, now I'm genuinely confused. Some people here seem to think it doesn't work. Unfortunately, I'm not good with Lebesgue (measure or integration) so I can't tell...

Comment: @Lelouch see the link in my first comment. Countable discontinuities are alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply no. People have been saying curious things here, perhaps thinking of the Lebesgue integral. And the result at the link requires stronger hypotheses.

Standard counterexample: if $f(x)=1$, $K=0$, $E=[a,b]\cap\Bbb Q$ then $f$ is integrable but $g$ is not.

Comment: Let me write down the math, you're saying $f(x) =1, \, \forall x \in [a,b]$ and then we define $$g(x)= \begin{cases} 1, \ x \in [a,b] \setminus ([a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}) = [a,b]\setminus \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 , \, x \in [a,b] \cap ([a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q})= [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$ So far so good? But now $g$ is discontinuous at *countably infinite* points, don't we have this [result](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) that suggests $f$ is **Riemann integrable** if set of discontinuities is countable? (Countable sets have measure $0$)

Comment: @William Yes the issue with Riemann integrability. My comment only looked at Lebesgue’s take on the matter ... I hadn’t read you wanted to know if $g$ was *Riemann* integrable.

Comment: $g$ will be Lebesgue integrable, however, with Lebesgue integral $\int g=\int f$. David’s example is a classic example of a Lebesgue-but-not-Riemann integrable function

Comment: @FShrike I have edited my question to clear the notation ambiguity. Also how is it not Riemann integrable? (See my comment below the answer.)

Comment: @William I believe that $g$ (better known as the indicator $1_{\Bbb Q}$, or “Dirichlet’s function” - I think) is in fact discontinuous everywhere. If you want an example, similar to $g$, with only countably infinite discontinuities, you can check out *Thomae’s function*

Comment: @FShrike Oh looks I've blundered big time. I was thinking "Oh look $g(x)$ is $1$ at every point except rationals." So I thought the set of discontinuities is all the rationals in $[a,b]$, never even considered irrationals. HA HA HA, guess I might as well quit math, move to countryside and raise chickens at this point :') Thank you both.

Comment: You can do math *and* raise chickens :D

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich so the conclusion is changing function values at finite number of points doesn't change value of Riemann integral but changing at infinite points does. Right?

Comment: right..........